# Symfony2 - doctrine2 batch processing

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, batch-processing

I have the following situation:

I need to create a large number of entities (Entity C) based on a pair of entities

- Entity A (45)
- Entity B (700000+)
- Entity C (45 x 700000)
- Entity D

So I decided to do the following:

```
$AEntities = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:EntityA')->findAll();
$DEntity = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:EntityD')->findOneBy($params);

$iterableResult = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:EntityB')
                ->createQueryBuilder('b')
                ->getQuery()->iterate();
$batchSize = 50

while (($row = $iterableResult->next()) !== false) {
  foreach($AEntities as $AEntity) {
    $entity = new Entity\EntityC();
    $entity->setEntityD($DEntity);
    $entity->setEntityB($row[0]);
    $entity->setEntityA($AEntity);
    $em->persist($entity);
  }

  if(($i % $batchSize) == 0){
    $em->flush();
    $em->clear();
  }
  $em->detach($row[0]);
  $i++;
}

$em->flush();
```

i follow instruction from [doctrine2-batch-processing](http://www.doctrine-project.org/blog/doctrine2-batch-processing)

but when i execute `$em->detach($row[0]);` and flush get an error A new entity was found through the relationship...

I have tried without `$em->detach($row[0]);` but this high memory consumption

**I need**: is to free the memory of each Entity B, after use, but at the same time each flush or by groups and not one by one, and clear all Entity C

Comment: It's not necessary to detach your entity as you regulary clear your entity manager.

Comment: this work fine if execute `$batchSize=50`, but isnot a good number for me

Comment: It's because you detach your entity before flushing so it's considered as a new entity by the entity manager...

Answer (score 1):

Calling [clear() on entity manager](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.0/doctrine/orm/entitymanager.html#clear%28%29) detaches ALL objects (by default). Btw, you can pass entity name to detach entities of given type:

```
$em->clear('EntityB'); 
$em->clear('EntityC');
```

I think you're trying to detach already detached entity and therefore it's treated as new.

Try removing `clear()` call. You might also try removing `detach()` call and call `clear()` on selected entities.

Comment: i get `[Doctrine\ORM\ORMException] EntityManager#clear($entityName) not yet implemented.`

Comment: It seems to be implemented in the master branch of Doctrine2 : https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2

Comment: i have installed `2.1.4` is the last included in the with `Symfony 2.0.7`

Answer (score 1):

You have to fully specify the entity name

```
$em->clear('Acme\MyBundle\Entity\EntityB');
$em->clear('Acme\MyBundle\Entity\EntityC');
```